# Producing pink plasma

Tags: science-based, technology

How to produce a pink coloured plasma (ionized state of matter )? what compounds must mixed that allows them to produce this coloured plasma

Comment: Hi Hkknnm, thanks for joining us on Worldbuilding. For the record, our purpose is to help you develop and consistently use the rules and systems of a fictional world of your own design. Betimes Real World questions are involved in that process, but we insist that there be a process (a fictional world of your own design) they are involved with. Straight-up science questions like this one are off-topic and should be asked at either [physics.se] or [chemistry.se]. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

I do believe Helium is the one you want.

Although "neon" light makers that want pink, will rather use a mixture 40/60 of Argon and Xenon, because that silly Helium *just refuses to stay in the glass tube!!*

[image]

Answer (score 4):

**I got your pink plasma right here!  Plasma, say Hy!**

[image: hydrogen plasma]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gas-discharge_lamp

Different gas plasmas emit characteristic colors when charged with electricity.  Above: hydrogen.  If hydrogen is too magenta you could use nitrogen.

[image: nitrogen]

Pink plasma, yep.  That's what it is.

Comment: And in general, a [discharge tube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gas-filled_tube). Used to be very common, from fluorescent lamps to neon signs; but nowadays they have been replaced with LED lights. I am partial to the pink glow of argon.